# Cannot connect to MySQL server on Openshift

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

Recently, I've started using openshift & also deployed an application using PHP & MySQL. Yesterday, out of curiosity, I've removed the password for phpMyAdmin and guess what, now I'm unable to log in to both phpMyAdmin & mysql database.

I've tried both the passwords (the default one & the empty password) and uninstalled & re-installed the PHPmyAdmin catridge & also, force restarted the app several times but nothing worked. Now, I've no idea what happened. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe reinstalling mysql server...

Comment: But, I'm afraid It'd erase all the data stored.

Comment: You could also run mysql on safe mode and create a new password for your root...just follow those steps: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password

Comment: I'm talking about Openshift not rackspace. :)

Comment: The steps are the same...good luck ;)

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. It seems,I need to enter the old password,which doesn't exist, in order gain the access. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: You couldn't start mysql on safe mode...that's weird :)

Comment: I don't have a good touch with command line but I tried this `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` & and got a list of errors saying Permission denied.

Comment: You should try `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` ...

Comment: `sudo isn't recognised`. So, I've tried without `sudo`, It gave me the Permission denied error. I'm on windows using Ruby command prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully this will help.

I assume what you did was go into phpmyadmin and click on 'users' then 'edit privileges' for one of the users, select 'no password' and hit save right?  If so, then I think the following steps should help.

1.)  ssh into your gear (you can use the rhc ssh command)
2.)  run the `mysql` command
3.)  You should get an error like this `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'adminslULJTS'@'127.10.126.130' (using password: YES)`
4.)  Now, type in the command `mysql -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST -P $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT -p`
5.)  When it asks for a password, just hit enter
6.)  You should now be logged into the mysql shell

Now you need to reset your password to what openshift thinks it is.

1.)  create another ssh session into your gear in another terminal, leaving the old one open
2.)  run the command `env | grep MYSQL`
3.)  this will give you the following information that you will need to reset your password:

```
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.10.126.130  
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=Il8-rVLIKSrx  
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=adminslULJTS
```

Given the above information, go back to your ssh session that had the mysql connection open, and enter the following command:

```
set password for 'adminslULJTS'@'127.10.126.130' = PASSWORD('Il8-rVLIKSrx');
```

But you will need to replace the username, host, and password with the ones you got from the above step.

You should now be able to log into phpmyadmin with your old username & password that you can either view using the `env | grep MSYQL` command, or view in the web console for your application at openshift.com

It also might be worth reviewing this KB article: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1085-possible-complications-when-changing-your-database-credentials

Comment: Pretty neat explanation and it worked well!! Thank you very very much. :)